# PHP string length of addslashes

Tags: php, string, special-characters

Can anyone explain how I escape a double quote " character within a string variable so that the ensuing string is only 1 character in length?

With addslashes it returns 2 chars:

```
$str = '"';
var_dump(addslashes($str));
```

string(2) "\""

But if its a string literal, its only 1 char:

```
var_dump("\"");
```

string(1) """

Comment: `var_dump('\"');` with single quote

Answer (score 1):

In a string literal, the slash is an escape character. So `\"` means the same as `"`.

If you want to add a slash to a string literal, then the slash must be escaped: `\\"`

If you use `addslashes` then it will also *add the slash character to the string*.

There is no way to add a character to a string without making that string longer.

Comment: Thanks Quentin. So is their a way of determine whether the $str needs a slash? Rather than indiscriminately concatenating like so:
    "\\" . $str

Comment: @Globalz — By knowing what you are going to use it for.

Comment: The string in question is user generated (choose an enclosure for a csv file). So I dont know if the string will be a special character that requires a slash or a normal character

Comment: I've no idea what "an enclosure for a csv file" is, but in general if you ask the user for something then work on the assumption that they are going to give it to your in the format you ask for it in. If you ask for text, then escape it for whatever format you need it in. If you ask for it preescaped, then just check that it is valid.

Comment: @YourCommonSense cryptic & unhelpful

Comment: @Globalz — No, he's being helpful and clear, but I'll rephrase anyway: "Your problem is not about how to add a slash to a string without making the string longer. You have asked a completely different question as a comment on an answer. That question should be asked as an actual [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)".

Comment: @Quentin ok I'm obviously unfamiliar etiquette/rules for stack overflow... Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing **PHP code** with plain data.

```
\"
```

is just a string consists of 2 characters

```
"\""
```

is a **PHP code** that evaluated into single `"` character, according to [syntax rules](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)